# An easy way to determine the space-like and time-like paths on a spacetime manifold based on linear algebra?

Tags: general-relativity

I think I have found a way to easily understand time-like and space-like paths with the contect of a little linear algebra. My question is: is my understanding, below, correct?

When I learned General Relativity, one source of some confusion was how to find the actual time or distance from a metric. In particular, suitable co-ordinates are just suitable co-ordinates and don't necessarily correspond to the actual physical time a clock, or a meter rule would actually measure. For that, you need to pick out the time-like, or space-like paths and integrate along them. I always found it a bit vague how to identify which was which.

Now however, based on some simple linear algebra, I think I have found way that makes it all very easy. I wanted to ask if it is correct or not.

I start with a metric in any suitable set of coordinates. In the analysis below I will eventually choose a time co-ordinate that measures time in meters (so that c is absorbed into the time and does not clutter the equations). The mathematical result is much clear this way. So I start with a metric that has been given to me by some GR calculation:

$ds^{2}=g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$

In linear algebra, this is just a "quadratic form", i.e. it is a symmetric bi-linear map of the form

$ds^{2}=dx^{T}Mdx$

where dx is a 4D column matrix, M is an invertable a symmetric 4 by 4 symmetric matrix, and the superscript T denotes transpose.

It is very easy to show that there is a linear transformation, P, of coordinates that will put M in "canonical" form, with all -1s or +1s on the diagonal. In the case of a metric tensor from General Relativity, the canonical form of M will be $\Lambda$ given by

$\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Thus, our initial metric can be written out in new coordinates as follows

$ds^{2}=dq^{T}\Lambda dq$

where

$dq=Pdx$

$\Lambda=PMP^{T}$

and another property of symmetric matrices, of course, is that the vectors associate with the coordinates in $dq$ will be orthogonal.

So let $dq=\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
dx_{p_2}\\ 
dx_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}$ and $dx=\begin{bmatrix}
dt\\ 
dx_{1}\\ 
dx_{2}\\ 
dx_{3}
\end{bmatrix}$

Then in these new coordinates, the metric becomes

$ds^{2}=-dt_{p}^{2}+dx_{p_1}^{2}+dx_{p_2}^{2}+dx_{p_3}^{2}$

I have used of subscript p here, since, to me, these seem to be physical coordinates. These will not be the only choice of such coordinates that will have this property; the action of any member of the Poincare' group on these coordinates will of course bring about another set of coordinates with the same property.

The point is that I believe that when we have the metric in this form, then if we go from coordinates

$\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
dx_{p_2}\\ 
dx_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
dx_{p_2}\\ 
dx_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

then I believe that we would have traveled through space an actual actual physical distance of 1m (without the passing of any time).

Similarly, if we traveled from

$\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
dx_{p_2}\\ 
dx_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
dx_{p_2}\\ 
dx_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

I believe we will have advanced in time by 1m  (in seconds this would be $(1m)/(3\times 10^{8}m)$ = 3.333 nanoseconds), but we would not have moved in space.

Thus, if I am right, a little elementary linear algebra makes it really easy, not only to pick out the time paths and space paths, but also to obtain coordinates consistent with the actual time or distance you would measure with a clock or meter rule. I was able to use this method to obtain the time dilation caused by Schwarzschild metric associated with a non-rotating black hole, so I think I am probably on the right track, but:

MY QUESTION IS THIS: is my analysis, above, correct?

I tend to find that if I can expressed the problem in the language of mathematics and see what is actually going on under the bonnet with the mathematics, it actually makes it much easier for me to understand the actual physics.

Answer (score 0):

You say: "It is very easy to show that there is a linear transformation, P, of coordinates that will put M in "canonical" form, with all -1s or +1s on the diagonal." This is true at any one point. However, it's not true in a neighborhood. For any small 4-dimensional region of spacetime, $M$ can be put in canonical form everywhere in the region if and only if the spacetime is flat.

Another point: You write $\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
dx_{p_2}\\ 
dx_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$, but you mean $\begin{bmatrix}
t_{p}\\ 
x_{p_1}\\ 
x_{p_2}\\ 
x_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$. This distinction is important - if you're ok with $dq$ being an arbitrary differential form, then you can put $M$ in canonical form everywhere. The problem is that you want $dq$ to correspond to some choice of coordinates $q$, so you need $dq$ to be closed.

Now, for any particular path, I think you can find a choice of $P$ that puts the metric in canonical form everywhere along the path. If you do this, you'll end up reinventing the usual approach, but it might make more sense to you once you've derived it from this perspective.

Comment: No, actually I do mean

$\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
dx_{p_2}\\ 
dx_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$ to $\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
dx_{p_2}\\ 
dx_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

In the above, I am talking about an infinitesimal quantity. In the scale of the Schwarzschild radius, 1m is essentially infinitesimally small.

Comment: Of course P will be a function of position, but as the manifold is smooth, P will be continuous. You will be able to integrate 

$\begin{bmatrix}
dt\\ 
dx_{1}\\ 
dx_{2}\\ 
dx_{3}
\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}(x)\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
dx_{p_2}\\ 
dx_{p_3}
\end{bmatrix}$
 
As x varies (where x are your original coordinates). So you could for instance integrate along

$\begin{bmatrix}
dt\\ 
dx_{1}\\ 
dx_{2}\\ 
dx_{3}
\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}(x)\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
dx_{p_1}\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

giving you a space curve parameterized by $x_{p_1}$

Comment: Or you could choose to integrate along 

$\begin{bmatrix}
dt\\ 
dx_{1}\\ 
dx_{2}\\ 
dx_{3}
\end{bmatrix}=P^{-1}(x)\begin{bmatrix}
dt_{p}\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$
giving you a time curve parameterized by $t_{p}$